# what should be the CSS code for IE 8+ browsers

Tags: css

I need to draw box like below image in our asp.net html page.

I am able to generate simple box, but how to put an extra layer on right and bottom.

Please suggest me what CSS can be used? please help with CSS code.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to _put an extra layer on left_? or is it right?

Comment: Do you mean **right** and bottom? - Google search *'CSS Box Shadow'*

Comment: have you try online box-shadow generator ?

Comment: i suppose box shadow will not work with IE8? what should be the solution for IE8+?

Comment: `CSS3` does't support on ie 8 or its older versions.. better put it as a bgimage for ie8 or lesser version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need box-shadow.

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/A7BfF/3/).

Comment: i suppose box shadow will not work with IE8? what should be the solution for IE8+?

Comment: I updated my link, play with filter params to recieve result, that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your box layer style.

```
div{   

 background:#fff;
 width:200px; height:200px;
 box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,1) 1px 1px,
               rgba(0,0,0,1) 2px 2px,
               rgba(0,0,0,1) 3px 3px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.elementClass OR #elementId {
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

Should do the trick. Just change the 5px until you get the right size.

Also, generally you should be showing your own attempts first. This is not a site that does work for you, rather offers suggestions on work that has already been started. This will greatly increase the chances of your question being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The effect above is box-shadow effect:

Try this:

```
div
{
width:300px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="logbox"></div>

.logbox{
   height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;
}
```

Comment: i suppose box shadow will not work with IE8? what should be the solution for IE8+?

Answer (score 0):

use the filter property:

```
/* For IE 8 */      
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, 
 Color='#000000')";     
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */        
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, 
Color='#000000');
```

I hope this will work fine for you.